# Using python, how do I launch an independent python process

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.2, code-cleanup, atexit

I am making a python program, lets say A. Which is used to monitor python script B

When the python program shuts down, there is an exit function that as registered via atexit.register(), to do some clean up it need to re-run python script B, which need to stay running even when python script A has shutdown.

Python Script B can't be part of Python Script A.

What do I need to do to make that happen, I have already tried a few things like using subprocess.Popen(programBCommand), but that doesn't seem to work as it prevents A from shutting down.

I am using a Debian Operating System

Comment: Why can't you do this a better way?

Answer (score 0):

If script B needs to be launched by script A, and continue running whether or not A completes (and not prevent A from exiting), you're looking at writing a UNIX daemon process. The easiest way to do this is to use the [`python-daemon` module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-daemon/) to make script B daemonize itself without a lot of explicit mucking about with the details of changing the working directory, detaching from the parent, etc.

Note: The process of daemonizing, UNIX-style, detaches from the process that launched it, so you couldn't directly monitor script B from script A through the `Popen` object (it would appear to exit immediately). You'd need to arrange some other form of tracking, e.g. identifying or communicating the pid of the daemonized process to script A by some indirect method.